# How to make a very basic WYSIWYG?

Tags: javascript

Do you know how to make a html editor or wysiwyg using javascript? I have tried so many editors but it seems all those that i tried doesn't give me the result that i want.

Command that I want to be available are:

bold

italic

underline

insert image

Copy-paste is ok but what i want to restrict is that when someone paste a clickable link, a table or anything that has a html format except for those 4 commands.

Comment: What editors have you tried? You can have a pretty basic http://ckeditor.com/

Comment: What's wrong with [this](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php), you can customize it with basic features.

Comment: Don't make a very basic WYSIWYG. Use a one that's made and see how it works. Otherwise you will end up spending a lot of time and making a crappy editor.

Comment: @Matt: i have tried many so many editor, ckeditor and the likes but non of them is what i am looking for.

Comment: the one has been very close to what i am looking for is this one http://www.themaninblue.com/experiment/widgEditor/ but it still accepts many html tags like table, h1, h2 and more.

i don't need a very fancy or have some many features. just only the 4 of those commands is ok.

Comment: then you could modify the widgEditor source code to disable those features you don't need

Comment: Captain kurO will try that. Anyways do you have a resources for the regular expression for remove hmtl tags format? thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for. It's jQuery. Just hook it up to a textarea by #id and you're ready to rock. You can disable buttons to make the most basic editor.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.wysiwyg.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#wysiwyg').wysiwyg();
});
</script>

<textarea id="wysiwyg"></textarea>
```

Here: http://akzhan.github.com/jwysiwyg/

Try this one as well
http://nicedit.com/index.php